# PHP Check for Duplicate Certificate Number MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that accepts multiple inputs and then submits it to the database however there is a field which holds the certificate number for a record I would like to query the database before the data is inserted to ensure that the certificate number is not already present. Can i do this when the field is entered i.e when the user tabs out of the field and then display a notification?

If so can someone post an example on how to do this.

The MySQL table is called - contract
The MySQL field is called - guarantee_no

The Form POST's to create.php (Code Below)

```
<?php
    include "includes/connection.php";

    $installer      = $_POST['inputInstaller'];
    $fitter         = $_POST['inputFitter'];
    $guarantee      = $_POST['inputGuaratnee_no'];
    $equipment      = $_POST['inputEquipment'];
    $certificate    = $_POST['inputCertificate_no'];
    $installed      = $_POST['inputInstall_date'];

    if(!$_POST['submit']){
        echo "Please Enter Data into the Form";
        printf("<script>location.href='index.php'</script>");
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contract (`id`,`user_id`,`installer`,`fitter`,`guarantee_no`,`contact_id`,`equipment`,`certificate_no`,`install_date`)
                       VALUES(NULL,'1','$installer','$fitter','$guarantee',NULL,'$equipment','$certificate','$installed')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Guarantee Record was Added, Thank You!";
        printf("<script>location.href='index.php'</script>");
    }               
?>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: i really hope in your real code you have some validation here....

Comment: I am new to PHP so I haven't started to look at validation, any suggestions / examples would be gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Question. If you want to use that validation in PHP. You can use `$_SESSION` variables.

In your action file.
Use:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "includes/connection.php";

    $installer      = $_POST['inputInstaller'];
    $fitter         = $_POST['inputFitter'];
    $guarantee      = $_POST['inputGuaratnee_no'];
    $equipment      = $_POST['inputEquipment'];
    $certificate    = $_POST['inputCertificate_no'];
    $installed      = $_POST['inputInstall_date'];

    if($installer == '' || $fitter == '' || $guarantee == '' || $equipment == '' || $certificate == '' || $installed == ''){
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'error';
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contract (`id`,`user_id`,`installer`,`fitter`,`guarantee_no`,`contact_id`,`equipment`,`certificate_no`,`install_date`)
                       VALUES(NULL,'1','$installer','$fitter','$guarantee',NULL,'$equipment','$certificate','$installed')") or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
   }               
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Now in your `index.php` file.
Use at the top:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['status'] == 'error') {
$msg = "Fill all form fields";
}
if ($_SESSION['status'] == 'success'){
$msg = "Record succesfully added";
}
?>
```

Now use that `$msg` variable where you want to print the message.
like:

```
<?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : '' ?>
```

**Note:** If you dont want to reload the page then Ajax with PHP should be used. This is just the simple way. You can Use accordingly.

Hope It helps..cheers..!!

Comment: Thanks for the really comprehensive answer I have questions though ;) in the error if statement the $certificate == has nothing in the quotation marks '' what would you place in there? also using @NullRef ajax / jquery method would i just call my create.php?

Answer (score 1):

Either you program it yourself, but since the clientside can't know about all usernames, you'll have to ask the server. Either by after submitting, telling the user the name was taking, or by using AJAX.

But I would advise you to **use one of the many already written plugins** out there.

I heavily recommand the [jQuery Validator Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) - they have an [example that does exactly what you want](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/), and you can see the code they use.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use AJAX. Your best bet to make it simple is to use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You need javascript like the following:

```
$("#your_form_element").blur(function(){
  $.ajax({
       url: "test_for_dupe.php?val=" & $(this).val(),
       context: document.body,
       success: function(){
         alert("Certificate already in DB!");
       };
 });

};
```

This is a generic example. Your field must have the ID = `your_form_element` and you need a PHP file called `test_for_dupe.php` that runs the query. You probably should look at jQuery examples and try to work this through. Post another question if you need more help. Hope this gets you going.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to get started with this.

Comment: @Neal: "when the user tabs out of the field". Explain to me how PHP can handle an onblur event...

Comment: @Neal: Because it sounds as though the OP wants to perform the check before the form is submitted: "Can i do this when the field is entered i.e when the user tabs out of the field and then display a notification?"

Comment: OUCH! @Neal, the only way to respond to the user on the fly that I know of is through AJAX.

Comment: Sorry @Mike I meant @Neal...my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The 'tab out' is doable, but would require an AJAX system to do the checking. Such systems are vulnerable to race conditions (e.g. tab out, everything ok, but in the 10 seconds it took for the user to reach for the mouse and click submit, someone else created the same record), so you'd still need submit-time checking as well.

As for the server-side checking, you'd simply do a `SELECT` query to look for the certificate number, and if any rows are returned, the cert # is in use. If it's in use, then don't do the insert. For better safety, you'd want to sprinkle some transactions and locking into the mix, so that the time between checking and inserting isn't vulnerable to poaching by other users.